# Convert single quoted elements in list to double quotes using python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Executing this code :

```
dictt = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3} 
tuple([i for i in dictt.keys()])
```

This result is :

```
['a','b','c']
```

But I want output to be :

```
("a","b","c")
```

The reason behind is i need the output to use it in a SQL QUERY

> INSERT INTO TABLE ("a","b","c") VALUES (1,2,3)

Comment: Why? Why does it make any difference at all?

Comment: that's a bummer because `json.dumps` yields `["a","b","c"]` so halfway :)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am using the tuple in a raw sql query "INSERT INTO TABLE ("a","b,"c") VALUES(1,2,3) single quotes doesn't work

Comment: There's something weird here. I can't replicate the output. I get `"('a', 'c', 'b')"`. Double quotes instead of backticks. And parens instead of square braces.

Comment: @paul100 Then post the actual problem and we may be able to help you. `'` and `"` does not matter.

Comment: @paul100 You can escape or you can use `"""` to make type of quote irrelevant.

Comment: Do this : `'INSERT INTO TABLE ("a","b","c") VALUES (1,2,3)'`

Comment: @SatishGarg just added the reason behind it

Comment: Well, *don't do that*. That really is not how you construct SQL queries in Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i am listening

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want to convert your key list as a string using this format.

A working way would be to use `json.dumps` which uses double quotes instead of simple quotes when serializing, and replace the enclosing brackets by parentheses (only the first-level ones):

```
import json

dictt = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

print("({})".format(json.dumps(sorted(dictt.keys()))[1:-1]))
```

result (as string):

```
("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: I am trying to get a new dict with keys double quotes, `b = {'"%s": %d' % (k, v) for k, v in dictt.items()}` . But the result `b` is type `set` contains `{'"a": 1', '"b": 2', '"c": 3'}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: in that case (that's not your question), just do `print(json.dumps(dictt))`, even simpler.